# mcs command not found when creating a DLL in mac develop unity3d

Tags: c#, dll, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

I follow this doc to create a dll file http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UsingDLL.html but the mcs command not found?

how to solve it?

I installed unity 4.5.1

I know this is the environment problem, so how to config the value in mac?

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer updated for OS X El Captain and Unity 5.2**

A usable `mcs` should be in `/Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/Frameworks/MonoBleedingEdge/bin/`.

It'll be easiest to add this dir to your `$PATH`, paste this in the terminal that you want to use (or to your startup scripts).

```
PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/Frameworks/MonoBleedingEdge/bin/
```

You should then have a working `msc` command:

```
$ mcs --version
Mono C# compiler version 3.4.0.0
```

---

**For other Unity versions:**

Open a terminal and type `find /Applications/Unity/ -name 'mcs'` - this will give you a list of `msc` compilers in your unity installation, for example my list looks like this:

```
/Applications/Unity/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.12/bin/mcs
/Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/Frameworks/Mono/bin/mcs
/Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/Frameworks/MonoBleedingEdge/bin/mcs
```

Check if any of these runs and pick that one. For 5.2, only the last one works without fixing paths inside the `mcs` script.